# share sqlite database between Adobe air and java in android?

Tags: java, android, database, air, share

I have an air app which creates a sql db on sd card and I am trying to access that db from my other java program... but java says that it can't access a read-only db file!

isn't it possible to share one .db between java and air?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the problem was that I had to connect to the database like this:

```
File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/someFolderName/app.db" ); 
SQLiteDatabase db2 = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
```

It is better to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of `/sdcard`
also don't forget to access the app by this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

one more thing : the file that I use has read and write permission. Maybe this cause to an error
it's great, now I can work with a very same `.db` both from `air` and `java` apps :)